# complexity of nT(n/2)+n

Tags: complexity-theory

what is the complexity for this code? i know the relation is T(n)=nT(n/2)+n

### Code

```
void methode(int n)     
 for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
   ifs1 = ifs1 + 1;
   if (n >= 1)
    methode(n / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method has a very unusual recurrence relation, `T(n) = n(T(n) + 1)`. I believe the asymptotic solution is

```
T(n) ∈ Θ(n^((log2(n)+1)/2))
```

or nicely formatted:

[image]

Let me know if you need me to spell it out in more detail.